# node.JS count object instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, oop

i have object with uniqe id and I want an auto id generator in the constructor.
I've tried this and its always stays 1
help please

```
getCounter  ()  {
        Product.counter = (Product.counter || 0) + 1;
        return Product.counter;
    }
this.id = getCounter();
```

Comment: Can you add a [mcve] to your question?

Comment: The code you've provided is syntactically incorrect, and it is logically incorrect. Simply having a global counter inside the constructor is probably not the right solution for whatever you're trying to do. Furthermore, for how it is provided right now it will probably work.

Comment: im trying to count instance of objects

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#field_declarations) instead?

```js
class Counter {

  // Initialise the counter
  constructor(counter = 0) {
    this.counter = counter;
  }

  // When `inc` is called increment
  // the counter value
  set(n = 0) {
    this.counter = this.counter + n;
    return this;
  }

  // Return the current counter value
  get() {
    return `Count: ${this.counter}`;
  }
  
}

// Create a new instance from the class
const counter = new Counter();

// Example: set the counter three times,
// and then return the current counter value
console.log(counter.set().set(5).set(10).get());
```